# Probability with unknown number of balls with respective colour.

Tags: probability

A bag contains 5 balls of unknown colours. A ball is drawn and replaced twice. On each occasion the ball was red. Again 2 balls are drawn at a time. What is the probability that the balls drawn are red? 
I tried using total conditional probability, taking cases like 3 other balls of all different colours, one red, and so on, adding up the probability of each case. 
How can we find the corresponding probability?

Comment: Seems to me you need some prior here.  If $R$ is the number of red balls in the bag, then did we imagine that there was an equal chance that $R=0,1,2,3,4,5$?

Comment: In reality there are so many other colors that I highly doubt that any of the other balls are red, so $\frac{2}{5}+ \text{ Some trivial amount, }$, but I'm not well versed in probability.

Comment: Well i was considering 5 different colours.. As any colour ball other than red is supposedly equivalent with the problem at hand?

Comment: The question seems to have some ambiguity. Problem is the word 'again' in combination with 'two balls drawn at time'. Given that 'a ball' is drawn and replaced twice. Two balls drawn at a time did not happen earlier. So how ' again'?